# Heroku error in Gitbash Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git-bash, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I cannot get Heroku to work in Gitbash on windows 10.

Gitbash `version = 1.9.4.msysgit.2`

Error Messages:

```
$ heroku version

/c/Program Files (x86)/heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 

line 1: @echo: command not found
/c/Program Files (x86)/heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 

line 2: setlocal: command not found
/c/Program Files (x86)/heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 

line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/Program Files (x86)/heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 

line 4: `if not "%HEROKU_REDIRECTED%"=="1" if exist "%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\client\bin\heroku.cmd" ('
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you,

Boba Fett

[My Windows Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R3Dp.png)

[The Error Messages in Gitbash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR2DG.png)

Comment: Have you tried searching google for those error messages?

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same error after I corrected the Path variable. What worked for me was installing a standalone version via bash. Uninstall the version of heroku that you have and then, in your shell,  run the command  `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh`

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`) to test the heroku version `heroku --version` to confirm it is installed and also try to check where it is installed using the `where heroku` command